# Create a variable number of `sliderInput` in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My data is a matrix with a variable number of columns. Also , the range of values within the matrix is variable, too.
I want to build a variable number of `sliderInput`, each corresponding to one column in the matrix. 
The higher limit of each slider should correspond to the `maxRange` within the matrix.
Any suggestion how to do it in one shot?

```
 lapply(1:ncol, function(i) {
        sliderInput(
          paste0('a', i), 
          paste0('SelectA', i),
          min = min(c(1:maxRange)),
          max = max(c(1:maxRange)),
          value = c(1, maxRange),
          step =1
          )
      }
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had broadly similar problem when I wanted to create a set of input elements corresponding to values derived from the data set (min, max list of options, etc.). Broadly speaking, I would source all the required data via `global.R` and then reference the concepts in the elements, so on the lines of getting `min/max` in a slider:

***global.R***

```
# Get dates for the slider
## Delete pointless month
dta.nom$DATE_NAME <- sub("February ", replacement = "", x = dta.nom$DATE_NAME)
## Convert to number and get min/max
dta.nom$DATE_NAME <- as.numeric(x = dta.nom$DATE_NAME)
yr.min <- min(dta.nom$DATE_NAME)
yr.max <- max(dta.nom$DATE_NAME)
```

Then in the slider

***ui.R***

```
# Select the dates for the data
sliderInput("sliderYears", label = h5("Years"), min = yr.min, 
            max = yr.max, value = c(2000, 2010), sep = "",
            step = 1, animate = FALSE),
```

Full code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/konradedgar/ShinyNomis). I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but if you are interested in dynamically connecting elements of your interface in Shiny then you can make use of the [updateSelectInput](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/updateSelectInput). Any other problems with respect to referencing the data should be solvable with use of `global` code and referencing the values in your interface elements.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Just to make sure I got it right, correct me if I'm wrong...by creating `global.R` all variables are visible in both, `ui` and `server` side as soon as the user opens the page. Therefore, for the global variables, there is no need to send a request to the server and they can be used immediately in the browser for some computations.

Comment: @flamenco, yes that's correct. The global objects are loaded into the global environment of the R session, there is a good note on using `global` scripts on [Shiny's website](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html).

Comment: I used your hint on `global.R` and came up with the solution posted above. It provides an adjustable number of `sliders` based on number of columns, different for each of the  `data1, data2, data3, data4`

Answer (score 1):

In case someone might bump into the same problem, here is my solution:

#### ui.R

```
    .... 
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(
            inputId = "dataName",
            label   = "Select your data",
            choices = c("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4")
          ),

        uiOutput(outputId = "sliders")
    ),
   .....
```

#### server.R

```
  .....
  output$sliders <- renderUI({
      numSliders <- numCols(input$dataName)
      lapply(1:numSliders, function(i) {
        sliderInput(
                    inputId = paste0('column', i),
                    label = paste0('Select the range for column ', i),
                    min = min(selectRange(input$dataName)),
                    max = max(selectRange(input$dataName)),
                    value = c(min(selectRange(input$dataName)), max(selectRange(input$dataName))),
                    step =1)
        })
    })
........
```

`selectRange` is a another function in `global.R`:

#### global.R

```
selectRange <- function(x){
  if(x == "data1"){choices = c(1:100)}
  if(x == "data2"){choices = c(1:50)}
  if(x == "data3"){choices = c(1:75)}
  if(x == "data4"){choices = c(1:150)}
return(choices)  
}
```